# Windows 7 Firewall: Add ESP8266 Access Point to trusted networks, how?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, wireless-access-point, windows-firewall, ad-hoc-network

Windows 7 Firewall: Add ESP8266 Access Point to trusted networks, how?

I made an Access Point (Ad Hoc) device with an ESP2866 that Windows needs to connect to (Wireless, WiFi). I tried several other devices to do this and works great, however, Windows won't do it.

Figured out it has something to do the Firewall.

- When I turn the firewall off, it connects without any problem.
- When connected and turn the firewall on again, it works still ok.
- However, when I disconnect and reconnect again, the same problem occur.

What can I do to make it work without this problem? Why Windows Firewall blocks the connection of this network by default? Never experience this behaviour before.

Some info of the ESP device:

```
- Own network, no internet access
- Provides DHCP and DNS
- Have a HTTP-Server started on port 80
```

Log:

```
Device starting: MorsTec - Clock Sound Dock CSD181
Version: v2018.1
Setup as Access Point ADHOC connection
IP address: 192.168.10.10
DNS server started at port 53 as "mtcsd"
TCP server started at port 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally found it, use `netsh` to add a filter to the system (thanks everyone :-( , thought this forum was about computer and networking?). Anyway this is the solution:

Open a dosshell and type:

```
netsh wlan add filter permission=allow ssid="Name-Of-Network" networktype=adhoc
```

Where `Name-Of-Network` is the name of the network (SSID).

That's it.
More info at:
https://www.eightforums.com/threads/wireless-networks-allow-or-block-with-filter-in-windows.45598/

Comment: not working on my windows 10 with Windows Defender Firewall on

Comment: @JasonHsieh This question was about Win7 and it is 4 years old. Maybe on Win10 you need to do this in a powershell  (other command I quess) instead of a dosshell. Be sure you do on an elevated prompt. I don't use Win10 because it sucks in all kind of fields. I am not able to help you, maybe it is time to ask a new question. But as you can notice already, user support isn't great on SU. Good luck.